# NSTableViewCell showing , for int

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

I recently installed Mountain Lion and noticed that my Mac OS X app that has data bindings now is showing an int32 NSTableViewCell as x,xxx.

IE: The `.storedata` file shows `<attribute name="itemid" type="int32">2533</attribute>` while the item is displayed in the cell as `2,533`. I cannot figure out why it does this in Mountain Lion but didn't in Lion.

How do I get the cell to show as `2533` instead of `2,533`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a Value Transformer

```
@implementation ItemIdValueTransformer

+(Class)transformedValueClass
{
    return [NSString class];
}

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation
{
    return NO;
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value
{
    // Remove the ,'s from Mountain Lion and up
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)[value integerValue]];
    return string;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat documented in the 10.8 release notes:

*NSString localized formatting*

*In 10.8, in apps linked against the 10.8 SDK, -localizedStringWithFormat:, and -initWithFormat:locale: (and friends) when supplied with a non-nil locale, will now do localized formatting of numbers. Previously these calls already did decimal point handling; so in some locales comma would be used for decimal point separator. This new behavior builds upon this to use localized digits as well as thousands separators and proper placement of the sign symbol.*

However I still consider it a bug (and filed it), there are many problems with it (screwing with legacy UIs, occasionally wrong behavior when edited by hand etc).

For new UIs you are probably best of adding a number formatter to your nib that you use for all text fields showing numbers.

If (like in my case) you have many nib files with even more text fields, this ugly hack may help:

```
#import "HHUTextFieldCell.h"

@implementation HHUTextFieldCell //:: NSTextFieldCell

//*****************************************************************************
// Class methods
//*****************************************************************************
+ (void)load {

    // 
    // 10.8 started using thousands separators for text fields. For our legacy
    // apps we don't want those. Rather than changing dozens of xib files with
    // hundreds of text fields, we use a replacement class to modify the text
    // fields to not have a thousands separator.
    // 
    [NSKeyedUnarchiver setClass:[HHUTextFieldCell class] forClassName:@"NSTextFieldCell"];
}

//*****************************************************************************
// Overwritten methods
//*****************************************************************************
- (void)setObjectValue:(id < NSCopying >)object {

    //
    // If `object` is an NSNumber object and no formatter is set, we instead
    // set the description of that number via -setStringValue:. Otherwise
    // use the original implementation.
    // 
    if(!self.formatter && [(NSObject *)object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    {
        [super setStringValue:[(NSObject *)object description]];
    }
    else
    {
        [super setObjectValue:object];
    }
}

@end
```